# Using JS for creating form document

Tags: jquery

This is my JS:

```
function validateEmail(emailaddress){  
       var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;  
       if(!emailReg.test(emailaddress)) {  
            alert("Please enter valid email id");
       }       
    }
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="newsletter">
Register Our NewsLetter: <input type="email" placeholder="example123@example.com" id="email"/>
<br><br>
<input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validateEmail('email')"/> 
</div>
```

**[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/lutukiyu/1)**
I requested from the submit button on-clicking at him to call `validateEmail` with the argument `email` which is the input.
It always returns me the alert, for unknown reason.
I've already checked it for million times and I couldn't find a mistake.

THanks in advance

Comment: *"This is my jQuery:"* There are no jQuery calls in that code snippet. That's JavaScript, but not using jQuery.

Comment: Sorry, mistaken. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're always passing the string "email" to your function, not the value of the input field.

Change:

```
<input id="gobutton" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validateEmail('email')"/>
```

to:

```
<input id="gobutton" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validateEmail(document.getElementById('email').value)" />
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/A5kv8/1/)**

Comment: +1 ...and don't use a really simplistic, incorrect email validation regex. :-) (And consider actually using jQuery, rather than 1995-era `onxyz` attributes.)

Comment: Thanks but somehow, the input allows space character to get in